# ExtJS - Window animation from right to left

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs6-classic

I am using Ext JS classic 6.2 and have created the animation below:

[image]

What i want to do now is make the window appear growing from right to left. Is it possible?

My code:

```
listeners: {
    afterrender: 'afterrender',
    close: () => MCLM.DrawHelper.finish(),
    show: (win) => {
        var painelEsquerdo = Ext.getCmp('painelesquerdo');
        var painelCentral = Ext.getCmp('painelCentral');
        var drawBtn = Ext.getCmp('drawBtn');

        win.setMinWidth(0);
        win.setX(painelEsquerdo.getWidth() + painelCentral.getWidth() - win.getWidth());
        win.setY(drawBtn.getY());
        win.setMinHeight(drawBtn.getHeight());
        win.setHeight(drawBtn.getHeight());

        var oldSize = win.getWidth();
        win.setWidth(0);

        win.animate({
            duration: 300,
            to: {width: oldSize}
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code looks odd -- I would only use Ext.getCmp on edge cases. Generally a better solution is to delegate your handler to controller (what you're doing with afterrender), and then get components by their reference using `lookup` method.

Comment: Yes. I moved the code to the window controller. I am using Ext.getCmp because that component is a window and the others are tabpanels outside, so i cannot use window.down()

Comment: lookup is different from down

Comment: Never used. I will look into it! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Code:

```
listeners: {
    show: (win) => {
        var painelEsquerdo = Ext.getCmp('painelesquerdo');
        var painelCentral = Ext.getCmp('painelCentral');
        var drawBtn = Ext.getCmp('drawBtn');

        // Efeito de expansão partindo do tamanho zero
        win.setMinWidth(0);

        var oldSize = win.getWidth();

        // Por alguma razão, a janela aparece uma vez antes da animação começar onde X estiver setado 
        // por isso, o width é zerado e o X é jogado para fora da tela
        win.setWidth(0);
        win.setX(-9999);

        // Alinhamento com o botão do menu
        win.setMinHeight(drawBtn.getHeight());
        win.setHeight(drawBtn.getHeight());
        win.setY(drawBtn.getY());

        // Em 150 milissegundos, diminui o X para a esquerda e aumenta o width para a direita
        win.animate({
            duration: 150,
            from: {
                width: 0,
                x: painelEsquerdo.getWidth() + painelCentral.getWidth()
            },
            to: {
                width: oldSize,
                x: painelEsquerdo.getWidth() + painelCentral.getWidth() - oldSize
            }
        });
    }
}
```

What i needed to do was decrease X and increase the window width from 0 so that every iteration moves X to the left (decreasing its value) and increases the window's width to the right.